# how to convert a time format string like "0M0.000s" to seconds in shell script

Tags: shell, time

how to convert a time format string like "0M0.000s" to seconds

please tel me the calculation

or plz tel me how can i make it possible in shell script

Answer (score 0):

```
ts="0M0.000s"
minutes=${ts%M*}
seconds=${ts#*M}
seconds=${seconds%s} # strip trailing "s"
total=$(bc <<< "$minutes*60 + $seconds")
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: @DavidPostill: it strips the numbers out, multiplies one of them by 60, and adds them together.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the conversion:

```
awk -F'[Ms]' '{print 60*$1+$2}'
```

For example:

```
$ echo '1M2.34s' | awk -F'[Ms]' '{print 60*$1+$2}'
62.34
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[Ms]'`

  This tells `awk` to treat both `M` and `s` as field separators.
- `print 60*$1+$2`

  This tells `awk` to multiply the first field (minutes) by 60 and add it to the second field (seconds).  This produces the total time in seconds.

#### Use in a script

Suppose that we have the time in a shell variable `t` and we want to put the number of seconds into a string variable called `seconds`. Use:

```
t='1M2.34s'
seconds=$(echo "$t" | awk --posix  -F'[Ms]' '{print 60*$1+$2}')
```